# Installing mplsoccer into conda issue

Tags: anaconda, package

I can install mplsoccer into my command prompt using pip, but I am unable to install it into conda. I get the error message:

[Image shows error message inside conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFcXv.png)

I have been to anaconda.org, but I am unable to find a solution

Comment: Please always post errors as text, not as screenshots

Comment: If you have been on anacondo.org, did you [run a search](https://anaconda.org/search?q=mplsoccer+)? It means that no `conda` channels contain this package. Can you clarify why you expected `conda install mplsoccer` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of mplsoccer. It is now available in conda-forge: `conda install -c conda-forge mplsoccer`.